# Improve performance of a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have a MySQL query that is currently running at 2.5 seconds and I want to trim it down to 2 seconds max.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Distinct(c.id) 
FROM   `content` c 
       INNER JOIN `actions` AS action 
               ON c.parent_id = action.primary_id 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND c.site_id IN ( 1, 2 ) 
       AND c.type IN ( 'topic' ) 
       AND c.status = 'visible' 
       AND ( c.lock = 0 
              OR c.site_id = 1 ) 
       AND ( c.level IN ( 0 ) 
              OR ( c.level IN ( 10 ) 
                   AND action.user_id = 123 
                   AND action.type IN ( 'group_follow' ) ) ) 
ORDER  BY c.date_updated DESC 
LIMIT  20
```

Here are the current stats:

- table content has 55k rows
- table actions has 87k rows

For content, I have indexes on:

- parent_id (parent_id)
- user_id (user_id)
- type_status_date (type,status, date)
- type_status_updateddate (type, status, date_updated)
- site_id (site_id)
- type_status_level (type, status, level)
- type_parentid_level (type, parent_id, level)

For actions, I have indexes on:

- primary_id (primary_id)
- site_id (site_id)
- type (type)

Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks all!

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN <your query>` and provide the information that comes back.

Comment: Is this SQL auto-generated or do you have freedom to change it in any way you like?

Comment: What's with the `WHERE 1=1` and why are you using `IN` instead of `=` when there's only one condition? Does the number of conditions for these columns change?

Comment: @user113215 - I can pass multiple values for those fields based on settings.  Is there a big difference in performance between the two?

Comment: you can always [beautify your queries](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).

Comment: Removing `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is likely to give you a significant performance boost. Do you absolutely need it?

Comment: @MrC: I've read conflicting reports on the efficiency differences between = and IN, so I recommend trying both ways and noting the speed differences yourself.

Comment: On the whole, MySQL can only use one index per table in a query.  You should make composite ones covering the (most discerning) columns that you require.

Comment: @RonaldBarzell - I was using 1=1 because the functions receives a bunch of arguments to customize the query.  This was a good way to allow me to start all appends to the query with "AND".  Thoughts?

Comment: @MrC: Well 1=1 would be an unecessary comparison; however, your SQL engine might remove it anyway.  Again, I recommend pulling it out and see what happens.  The thing with optimizations is that some of them may be things the engine already does, so sometimes you just have to try them out and profile them.

Comment: I've found that `OR` tends to confound query optimizers.

Comment: @duskwuff - I use it for pagination of the contents (I get the max number using FOUND_ROWS)

Comment: @MrC: I'd strongly recommend that you consider dropping that. `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` forces the database server to generate the full result set, rather than just the number specified by `LIMIT`.

Comment: You need to show us the actual table and index definitions.  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing a "ORDER BY c.date_updated DESC LIMIT 20", you probably want an index on c.date_updated.  That way, mysql can scan that table first in reverse `date_updated` order and stop as soon as it gets the 20 rows.

You should definitely use `EXPLAIN` to check your query before and after the change, to see if the optimizer selects that order.  There are ways to force the use of the `date_updated` index if the optimizer doesn't select it naturally.

Answer (score 0):

in where clause you must have order. firsts must be a column that have a index.

for example for index 
type_status_updateddate (type, status, date_updated)

if we write

```
where status = 'blabla' and type = '1'
```

index  not using nut

```
where type='1' and status='blala'
```

use index.

mysql use index if column is left in index(in multi column index).
for example for index 
type_status_updateddate (type, status, date_updated)

if we write
    where status = 'blablabla'
index not using

this fact do using multicolumn indexes not cool

and

```
c.type IN ( 'topic' )
```

may be replace on

```
c.type = 'topic'
```

sorry for my english.